# Can the directional derivative fail to be linear?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is it possible for the directional derivative for a function $f$ in the direction of a vector $v$, $D_vf(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + hv) - f(x)}h$ to exist for every vector $v$, and yet $v \mapsto D_vf(x)$ fails to be linear? Here we have a function which seems to be displaying that very phenomenon:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{32x^3}{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{16x^5}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} - 14x$$
[image]

As you can see, if you follow the map at the origin in the direction of any vector, it appears to follow a straight line, i.e. the derivative in that direction is constant in the direction of $v$. Yet the "slope" in each direction is clearly not behaving in a linear manner. Is this really the case? Or is it just a misleading graph? I'm inclined to believe the former, but what I'm looking for is a rigorous argument.

Further, under what conditions might a derivative fail to be linear? Or, what are necessary conditions to ensure that a proof that "the directional derivative is linear" actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $ v\mapsto D_vF(x_0)$ is linear when the function $f$ is *differentiable* at $x_0$. In that case, there exists a linear map $ df(x_0)$ such that $D_vF(x_0)=\langle df(x_0),v\rangle $. There exist functions which have all the directional derivatives $D_vF(x_0)$ at a point $ x_0$, but fail to be differentiable, in particular the previous map is non linear.

Comment: I don't understand "in particular the previous map is non linear."

Comment: I mean that the map $ v\mapsto D_v F(x_0)$ is in general not linear (if it exists) when $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$

Comment: That's not true. Consider the function $f(x,y) = 0$ if $y=0,$ $f(x,y) = x^3/y$ otherwise. All directional derivatives are $0$ at the origin, so certainly the directional derivative is linear in $v,$ but $f$ is not even continuous at the origin.

Comment: Right, my statement could be ambiguous. I said that the map $v\mapsto D_vF(x_0) $ is in *general* not linear when the function is not differentiable at $x_0$. I used the term "in general" having in mind "not necessarly" . The clarification is  welcome.

Comment: It seems that your definition of "differentiable" boils down to "the directional derivative exists everywhere and is linear". Am I characterizing this correctly?

Comment: No, that is not correct and it was well exemplified by zhv. Differentiable means more (see for example the definition of "differentiability in higher dimensions" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function). Of course, your statement is implied by the notion of differentiability.

Comment: Looking at zhv's function, I don't believe that exemplifies how what I was saying could be mistaken. I mean, the directional derivative for that function exists, but it is certainly not linear! Would not linearity of the directional derivative imply differentiability in the sense described by Wikipedia? Or are there counterexamples to that particular statement?

Comment: Read carefully the example of zhv: in that case $D_v f(0)=0$ for any $v$. So the map $ v\mapsto D_v f(0)$, being the NULL MAP, is by sure linear. Nevertheless the function is NOT DIFFERENTIABLE at 0.

Comment: Ah, of course, that'll teach me not to make assumptions about a function by a casual inspection of its graph...

Answer (score 4):

Certainly this can happen. The classic example is $f(x,y) = xy/(x^2+y^2).$ If we let $v=(a,b),$ then $D_v(0,0) = ab/(a^2+b^2).$ The last expression is not a linear function of $(a,b).$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your function
$$f(x,y) = \frac{32x^3}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{16x^5}{(x^2+y^2)} - 14 x$$
I'll use the notation $D_x = D_{(1,0)}$ and $D_y = D_{(0,1)}$.  Then,
$$D_x f(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \frac{32h^3}{h^3} - \frac{16h^5}{h^5} - 14\frac{h}{h} = 2$$
and
$$D_y f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0,h) - f(0,0)}{h} = 0$$
But,
$$D_{(1,1)}f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,h)-f(0,0)}{h}= \frac{32h^3}{2h^3}-\frac{16h^5}{4h^5} - 14\frac{h}{h} = -2\not= D_xf(0,0) + D_yf(0,0)$$
So $D_v$ is not linear in $v$ at $(0,0)$.

---

In order for the directional derivative to be linear in $v$ at a point $x$, it is sufficient that the partial derivative $D_x$ and $D_y$ (and $D_z$, etc. for higher dimensions) be continuous at $x$.  To see why, observe that
$$D_{(v_x, v_y)} f(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+hv_xe_1+hv_ye_2) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+hv_xe_1+hv_2e_2) - f(x+hv_ye_2)}{h} + \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+hv_ye_2) - f(x)}{h}$$
The second term we recognize as $D_{(0,v_y)}f(x)= v_yD_yf(x)$, while by the Mean Value Theorem we can re-write the first term as
$$\lim_{h\to 0} v_xD_xf(x+hv_ye_2+ce_1)$$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $h$.  But, by the continuity of $D_xf$ near $x$, this limit is simply $v_xD_xf(x)$.  Thus,
$$D_{(v_x,v_y)}f(x) = v_xD_xf(x) + v_yD_xf(x)$$
is linear in $v$.

Comment: It is sufficient that f be differentiable at x for the direction derivative to be linear in v. Continuity of the partials at x implies differentiability at x; you don't need this continuity in a small ball centered at x, just at x.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks!  Reading your comment, I realized I'd only used continuity at $x$.  I've edited accordingly.